# Why won't my new skin load?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been trying to change my skin. I can see my skin, but everyone else sees me as Steve (the default skin). I need to change my skin or I will *explode in anger*. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Ari, welcome to Arqade. This question does not give very much detail, except as to your emotional state ;-) If you edit it to add some more detail about (for example) what you have tried and what error messages you face (if any), then you might find that the question it gets more attention. This will also help to clarify whether or not it is a duplicate of the questoin that 3ventic has linked above.

Comment: @3ventic Not a dupe, this is to do with the skin not appearing correctly for other people, not changing it in the first place.

Comment: If you are playing offline, or on a server with `online-mode` disabled, your skin cannot load from the profile servers.

Comment: did you upload it to minecraft? that's how I do it and now everybody sees me as a green Enderman.

Answer (score 6):

Skin changes can take a little while to propagate (and there could be any number of points at which the skin is cached by other players). It should change within an hour, make sure everybody quits and restarts Minecraft to have the best chance of the new skin loading quickly.